# Modular sum of square numbers in C++

Tags: c++, time-limit-exceeded, mathematics

So I've got an assignment which sounds like this:

> Given a number *n*, calculate the result of this sum, modulo 10,234,573:
>   1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + … + *n*<sup>2</sup>

This is what I've come up with :

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     uint n;
     cin >> n;

     uint num{10234573};
     uint64_t sum{0};
     for (uint i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
         sum += (i*i)%num;
         sum %= num;
     }

     cout << sum;

     return 0;
 }
```

And I can check my algorithm on a website, but it tells me that it is "too slow"... How can I optimise it so it will be faster?
I know there is a formula for this, but the given number *n* can be as big as 2,000,000,000, so it will obviously overflow...

Comment: There is a formula for the sum of series you described. Google for it or find yourself.

Comment: And I just said that it would overflow if, for example, n is 2,000,000,000...

Comment: It is not hard to solve that either. No googling = no learning.

Comment: Then could you please give me an idea of how could I do it?

Comment: it is better to learn to search for that yourself. You need a fishing rod, not fish. The answer lies in properties of modulo.

Comment: ( ( (n % num) * ( (n % num + 1) % num) * ( ( (2 * n) % num + 1) % num ) ) / 6 ) %num This is what I came up with, but now it tells me that 7 out of 10 tests give wrong results... Where is my mistake?

Comment: `10234573²` is much, much less than `2⁶⁴`, so you should easily be able to compute the closed-form expression using `n%10234573` with reductions in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Headers

You'll need to include `<cstdint>` to get a definition of `uint64_t`.  Actually, `uint_fast64_t` is probably a better choice, as it's fine if we have a wider type.

## Avoid `using namespace std;`

Importing all names of a namespace is a bad habit to get into, and can cause surprise when names like `begin` and `size` are in the global namespace.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

The exceptions to this rule are namespaces explicitly intended to be imported wholesale, such as the `std::literals` namespaces.

## Separate I/O from computation

Instead of bashing everything into your `main()` function, it's better to provide a *pure function* that's amenable to unit tests, and separately provide the means to drive that from positional parameters, standard input, file streams, GUI, etc.

## Use appropriate types

`uint` isn't a standard type; I'm guessing from the name that it's declared as an alias for `unsigned int` - in which case the minimum guaranteed `UINT_MAX` (65535) may not be sufficient for the problem requirements.  I think we should be using the same type for `i` and `n` as for `sum`.

## Use a more efficient algorithm

There is a simple formula for computing a [Square pyramidal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number): **(2n³ + 3n² + n) / 6**.  We can use this, as long as we keep intermediate values between 0 and `UINT_FAST64_MAX` (since 10234573² < 2⁶⁴, this can be done by reducing mod *m* before multiplying).

---

## Cleaned-up version

Applying all bar the last recommendation (and with input from arguments, for easier testing), I have:

```
#include <cstdint>

using Number = uint_fast64_t;

Number pyramidal_modn(Number number, Number modulus)
{
     Number sum{0};
     for (Number i = 1;  i <= number;  ++i) {
         sum += (i*i) % modulus;
         sum %= modulus;
     }
     return sum;
}



#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static const Number m = 10234573;
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        Number n = std::stoul(argv[i]);
        std::cout << n << ": " << pyramidal_modn(n, m) << '\n';
    }

    // test a large value
    const Number t = 123456798;
    return pyramidal_modn(t, m) != (pyramidal_modn(t-1, m) + t*t) %m;
}
```

We can now substitute with a more efficient implementation without changing any other code (in particular, without disturbing the tests):

```
constexpr Number pyramidal_modn(Number n, Number m)
{
    n %= m;
    auto n2 = n*n % m;
    auto n3 = n2*n % m;
    return (2*n3 + 3*n2 + n) / 6;
}
```

Note that we're now able to give it the `constexpr` qualifier.

(Exercise: why did we not need `% m` in the `return` statement?)

Comment: Well, n will be smaller than m, the same for n2 and n3... if we add 3 numbers smaller than m and then divide them by 6 the result will obviously be smaller than m. Am I right? Edit: in the worst case, n will be m-1 and let’s just say it could be the same for n2 and n3, so it will be 6*(m-1)/6, in the worst case scenario.

Comment: Yes, that's right - we're adding 6 numbers smaller than `m` (6 not 3, because of the `2*` and the `3*`), then dividing by 6, so the result can't exceed `m`.

Answer (score 1):

To use the modulo in equations, You need to maintain the equivalence of the Equation. The Equation you wrote in comment is not according to equivalence. [See Division Under Equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Equivalencies)

So, going by the equivalence you have to calculate it like this :

> [ ( (n) %x ) * ( (n+1) %x ) * ( ( 2*n + 1 ) %x ) ) * ( (1/6)%x ) ] %x

[Have a look at this](https://imgur.com/a/07uh3).

Note that this will not work If given n is any multiple of x. So, n & x must be [Co-prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers). In your case, x = 10234573 is already a prime number as pointed by Toby's Comment

Comment: 10234573 is clearly prime, which simplifies the reasoning.

Comment: Oh you’re right, you’re the only one who actually explained to me how does the distributivity of the modulus operator work. Thanks a lot !